# flake8 to ignore warning F405 on multiple lines

Tags: python, flake8

I am having a fabric script and i am using below statement

```
from fabric.api import *
```

Now i know this isn't as per PEP8 standards but this is really needed specially for a library like `fabric` and we can really import everything from it. Because of this `flake8` is complaining on multiple lines with `F405` code.

I have disabled this for one line using `#noqa` but since there multiple lines with same PEP8 violation how can i ask `flake8` to ignore this particular error code.

I have also tried `# noqa: F405` at the beginning of the file but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
[flake8]
ignore = E405
```

in your `.flake8` config file will work.

Flake8 itself does not support per-file configuration, see the post:
https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/156

But for advanced configuration, e.g. per-file, recommended way is to use `flake8-putty`

The homepage gives you an example:

> Disable only D102 on foo.py
>
> ```
> putty-ignore = foo.py : D102
> ```

Comment: But i don't want to ignore it globally, i want to ignore only for this file.

Comment: Per-file configuration is discussed in: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/156

Comment: Anyways i tried setting up `setup.cfg` and putting `ignore` in it and it still does not work.

Comment: Did you try `flake8-putty`, which is a recommended way there?

Comment: I have also tried with `.flake8` file but still this file is not loading and i am still seeing the errors/

Comment: What do you mean? File `.flake8` is loaded by default unless you have another file like `setup.cfg` or `tox.ini`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184670/discussion-between-rohit-and-grapes).

Answer (score 4):

Starting from version 3.7.0, flake8 supports per file ignores out of the box. You can check the documentation on the command line flag / config file option [here](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores)